# How to expand a variable within an array so the surrounding array is valid

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I'm having a problem I don't even know how to describe. I need to build a dynamic array, and include it within another array. Let me expand. Here's my code:

```
$myarrayarray = '';
$categoriesTerms = $catlist = rtrim($categoriesTerms,',');
$categoriestocheck = explode(',',$categoriesTerms);

foreach($categoriestocheck as $key=>$value){
    $myarrayarray .= "array(";
    $myarrayarray .= "'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',";
    $myarrayarray .= "'terms' => array(".$value."),";
    $myarrayarray .= "'field' => 'slug',";
    $myarrayarray .= "'operator' => 'AND'";
    $myarrayarray .= "),";
}           
$myarrayarray .= "array(";
$myarrayarray .= "'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',";
$myarrayarray .= "'terms' => array('event'),";
$myarrayarray .= "'field' => 'slug',";
$myarrayarray .= "'operator' => 'OR'";
$myarrayarray .= "),";
echo $myarrayarray;

$locationArgs = array(
    'post_type' => 'maplist',
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $orderdir,
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array($myarrayarray),
);

$mapLocations = get_posts($locationArgs);
```

This does not generate an error, it just fails to limit the data returns in any way. If I print my $myarrayarray variable, I get this for a search that combines paint and pressurized-cylinders:

```
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',
    'terms' => array('paint'),
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'AND'
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',
    'terms' => array('pressurized-cylinders'),
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'AND'
),
array(
    'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',
    'terms' => array('event'),
    'field' => 'slug',
    'operator' => 'OR'
),
```

if I put this in place of the variable in the code, it works great. So, the variable isn't malformed, it's just not resolving within the other array. Maybe I'm an idiot and this isn't possible? What am I doing wrong?!?!?! This is driving me insane and I don't even know how to phrase a search for a solution.

Comment: myarrayarray is just a string that looks like an array. Do a var_dump(array($myarrayarray)) (this is what you are passing to 'tax_query') and you should see that it is not in the correct format for 'tax_query'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're generating a STRING, not an array.

```
$str = 'hello,there';
$arr = array($str);
```

does NOT produce

```
   $arr = array(
       'hello', // element #1
       'there'  // element #2
   );
```

it produces

```
$arr = array(
    'hello,there' // single element #1
);
```

If you want to produce nested arrays, then skip the whole strings business

```
$data = array();
foreach($categoriestocheck as $key=>$value){
    $data[] = array(
       'taxonomy' => 'map_location_categories',
       'terms' => array($value.),
       etc..
    );
}
$locationArgs = array(
    ...
    data => $data
);
```

Comment: omg, you rock. that worked. my OR array wouldn't resolve, but I was able to create a second array with those results and merge the two. YOU ROCK!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$myarrayarray = array();

$categoriesTerms = $catlist = rtrim($categoriesTerms,',');
$categoriestocheck = explode(',',$categoriesTerms);
foreach($categoriestocheck as $key=>$value) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['taxonomy'] = 'map_location_categories';
    $tmp['terms'] = array($value);
    $tmp['field'] = 'slug';
    $tmp['operator'] = 'AND';
    $myarrayarray []= $tmp;
}

$tmp = array();
$tmp['taxonomy'] = 'map_location_categories';
$tmp['terms'] = array('event');
$tmp['field'] = 'slug';
$tmp['operator'] = 'OR';
$myarrayarray []= $tmp;

print_r($myarrayarray);
```

Either that, or use `eval($myarrayarray)` but have in mind that usage of `eval` is generally considered as evil.